# Issue with presenting an external UIView in a UIViewController: outlets don't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have a UIViewController that has its UI elements setup in storyboard, and things are showing up fine. Now I created a new UIView in separate xib, .h and .m files, I'll call it "overlay"; then I present that overlay which should cover everything below, so that only the overlay can be seen:

```
// in controller.m
OverlayView *overlayView = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
overlayView.layer.zPosition = 1000;
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

The overlay appears in a weird position (the top of it is some 50px away from the bottom of the navigation bar). What's more, apart from the background of the overlay, no elements in the overlay can be seen. It's just a blank red canvas. I have double checked that the elemenets' alpha values are 1, they are set to be not hidden, and they are also set explicitly in the `initWithFrame` of the overlay:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // red canvas shows up
        self.title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // title can't be seen; why not?
        self.body.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // body can't be seen; why not?
    }
    return self;
}
```

The reason I don't directly put overlay in the controller's xib and then simply change it's `hidden` property is that this overlay is to be used by multiple controllers, and I'd like to re-use it, thus putting it as a separate view.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The parent view (view controller's view) is responsable to set the child view's frame. If you use Auto Layout you need to use `setTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` and add the desired constraints in code. Keep in mind that the child's frame will be set after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called.
If you don't use Auto Layout just set the frame using `setFrame` method in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, just want to double check I understand you correctly: we are talking about one controller and two views here, first view is the controller's own view which I set in storyboard, second view is this overlay that I want to present over the controller's own view. So which child view are you talking about here?

Comment: Also, are you suggesting that I put the `[self.view addSubview:overlayView];` logic in viewWillAppear? I have already tried that, the result was the same. The frame was already set when I call `initWithFrame`.

Comment: No, the view should be added in viewDidLoad. In viewWillAppear you can access or change the frame if you need to and if you are not using Auto Layout. If you do use Auto Layout you should add constraints when the view is added in viewDidLoad and don't mess with the frame and you can access the frame only in viewDidLayoutSubviews. In viewWillAppear i don't think the frame is set yet. Again, is very important if you use or not Auto Layout.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to load the nib from within the view's own `initWithFrame`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    id mainView;
    if (self) {
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyOverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return mainView;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}
```

The code above fixed it.